Looking for a non completed Amiga PPC game
In the late 90s there was work on a 3d space trading game for a PPC equipped Amiga.  I'm trying to recall what the name of that game was, and who the developers were.  Does this ring any bells to anyone?

@knol Ok, will do :) I have zero knowledge of the Amiga scene or 3rd party graphics cards so if anyone has any other info please let me know and I will update my answer.

@Zenzizenzizenzic If Noel's answer is correct, please mark it as accepted (the checkmark below the voting buttons).

The game referred to may be Ankhrapt, by the Polish software development team Deck Six (now known as D6):


A preview of this game was included on the CU Amiga Magazine Super CD-ROM 27 cover disc and shows some of the gameplay elements, such as arming your spaceship and creating new colonies. A preview article in a Polish games magazine mentioned that the game would be similar to Reunion and would include "fights with aliens, expansion of colonies and fleets, and lots of menus" and PowerPC support was planned from the outset. According to the developers they may have had to drop their plans to use proprietary graphics adaptors and ran into issues trying to get the game's UI to work on the standard Amiga graphics chip.

Just a FYI, the English and Polish translations differ on the developer's web site but it seems that the developers dropped support for 3rd party graphics hardware because they weren't familiar enough with the hardware at the time. The team had several other projects underway during the development of Ankhrapt and they disbanded sometime around 2000.
